# c#- How can i show data in datagridview follow the field of database

Tags: c#, winforms

I have a winform application with a DataGridView, its DataSource is DataTable.
In DataGridView, there is a field follow from database( SQL Server), it's int type, but i want to show it with string when the DataGridView's loaded.

Example:

- In database, have a field, its name is gender, it have two value: 1 or 0.
- But I want to show it on DataGridView follow condition:
- if gender = 1 from database then show it on Cells["Gender"] is Male on DataGridView.
- if gender = 0 from database then show it on Cells["Gender"] is Female on DataGridView.

Thanks for everyone!

Comment: Have you checked IValueConverter? That is normally used to do this kind of conversion.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `CellFormatting` event

```
private void dataGridView1_CellFormatting(object sender, DataGridViewCellFormattingEventArgs e)
{
    if (this.dataGridView1.Columns[e.ColumnIndex].Name == "Gender")
    {
        if (e.Value != null)
        {
            int gender = int.Parse(e.Value);
            if (gender == 1)
            {
                e.Value = "Male";
            }
            else
            {
                e.Value = "Female";
            }            
            e.FormattingApplied = true;
        }
    }    
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use sql query 
string query="select case when gender=0 then 'Male' when gender=1 then 'Female' from yourTableName";

Answer (score 0):

There are couple of ways to get the answers.

1. First and easy way is to change the query you are running for the DGV. you can have CASE statement which returns male or female when column value is equal to 1 or 0. Code sample:

CASE 
  When [colunm_name] = 1 Then 'MALE'
  Else 'FEMALE'
END as alias_column_name

2. If you do not have acces to update the query then you can have a validation after loading the DGV.

   foreach (DataGridViewRow row in dataGridView1.Rows)
                   {
                       if (row.Cells[0].Value.ToString() == "1")
                       {
                           row.Cells[0].Value = "Male";
                       }
                       else{
                           row.Cells[0].Value = "Female";
                       }

   ```
               }
   ```